# How to create a PivotTable from an outside/online source

Tags: excel, office365

I am trying to create a pivot table with Excel 2013 using the information from a spreadsheet on Excel Online, how do I import from this spreadsheet into my pivot table? I am getting a message that the "type of connection selected cannot be used to create a Pivot Table.  I have searched Google for this issue and have not found much information. 
Any info on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Power Query to get the data from an Excel file stored on OneDrive.

You need the file's resid, which you can see when you share a file and get a link.

On the Power Query ribbon select "From Web" and enter

```
https://onedrive.live.com/download?&resid=fe123456789123f7!123
```

[image]

Then select the sheet you want and either edit the query or load right to your worksheet or to the Excel data model and create the pivot.